# React-Native App works on emulator [Oreo 8.1] but not on real device[redmi note 5 pro , Oreo 8.1]

Tags: react-native, android-8.1-oreo

[react-native run-android log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bN2u.png)

please ask for any sufficient data needed for the solution. also i am new in react-native and would like to learn more on it

Comment: add any errors from the app's screenshot or from logs of js server or from console

Answer (score 0):

Try To Clean And Rebuild The Project...

Use A Debugger To Debug The Code...

Check The API Levels...

Oh And Also Check Your SDK Manager On The Phone And Studio. Maybe All The Needed SDKs aren't Working Or Aren't Installed. Try Re-Installing Those...

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but i have checked all of the above given checks. all of them are appropriate.** do warnings can cause such error? **

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.
For me problem was hidden in createStore for redux
There I was checking if env is developement then adding redux debug support, otherwise not

```
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null || compose;
```

here I forgot to import compose from redux which is only required in the production mode when I tried the apk on mobile.

This may be the issue for you check your if(**DEV**) or above type of statement which should be good for production build.apk aslo